# Tooltip do pontos exibe entidades: pontua&#231;&#227;o de reputa&#231;&#227;o

Tags: bug, status-pronto, internacionalização

Passando o mouse por cima do número que mostra a reputação ao lado do imagem de algum usuário que postou uma pergunta ou resposta, debaixo do seu nome, e deixando o mouse lá parado algum tempo, um tooltip aparece:

[image: pontuação de reputação]

Ops, parece que temos um bug de escaping!

**EDIT:** Ah, e por sinal, acho que ficaria bem melhor "pontos de reputação" ao invés de "pontuação de reputação".

Comment: Neste momento está aparecendo como "pontos de reputa&#231;&#227;o". :)

Comment: removi os entities... foi vc que digitou assim ou o foi bug do site?

Comment: @DanielOmine O bug era exatamente de aparecer "pontua&#231;&#227;o de reputa&#231;&#227;o" no tooltip, e eu escrevi o título exatamente dessa forma para evidenciar o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema já encontra-se corrigido atualmente.